# Java password Program loops forever need help

Tags: java

Why is this Just repeating forever even when I enter a length more than 6 characters?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Password {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome please enter your username and password.");
        System.out.print("Username >>");
        input.nextLine();
        enterPassword();
        System.out.println("Successfully Logged In");
        }

    public static void enterPassword(){
        String password;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Password >>");
        password = input.nextLine();
        checkPasswordLength(password);
        }


    public static void checkPasswordLength(String password){
        int length;
        length = password.length();
        while (length <6){
            enterPassword();
            }
        checkPasswordLetter(password);
        }

    public static void checkPasswordLetter(String password){
        System.out.println("More checking here to be added");
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you not storing your username as anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
    length = password.length();
    while (length < 6){
        enterPassword();
    }
```

You never update `length`, even after obtaining a new password.

Here's a better way to organize your code:

```
public static String enterPassword() {
   //gets a string and returns it
}

public static boolean checkPasswordLength(String password) {
   //if too long return false
}

//...
String password = enterPassword();
while ( !checkPasswordLength(password) ) {
    password = enterPassword();
}
```

Comment: you are right, that length is never updated once inside the loop. But I feel the flow is fishy. checkPasswordLength() calls enterPassword() which in turn calls checkPasswordLength(). The program could be written with a very simple flow!

Comment: @cheekoo: you're right; I was editing that into my answer at the same time that you said that.  It's best to have a method have one responsibility, instead of inserting side-effect logic into the validation.

Comment: Great that works really well..One question though. My book doesn't teach me while ( !xxxxx(xxx) ) what is that called? I realize you are saying while not true. I would like to look at that deeper though to get a better understanding.

Comment: @allencoded: Looks like you've got the jist of it.  `!` means boolean negation...it inverts the truth value of a boolean expression.  So `while ( !(length < 6) )` would mean "while length is not less than 6" which is the same as "while length is greater than or equal to 6".  See [the Java tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) for more info on operators.  It might improve clarity to rename `checkPasswordLength` to something like `isPasswordLengthAcceptable()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues. The first is obviously that length doesnt change in your while loop, secondly enterPassword() doesnt actually change the password.

Also you are infinitely calling enterpassword that calls checklength that calls enterpassword that calls..... not sure if this is the best habit to get into.

You should try and break your functions into logical units of work so that they are more reusable.

enterpassword should enter the password, then checkpasswordlength should check the length independantly, IMO

how about something liek this?

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

class Password {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome please enter your username and password.");
    System.out.print("Username >>");
    input.nextLine();

    String password = "";

    //keep going until we get an acceptable password
    while(!CheckPassword(password))
    {     
    password = enterPassword();
    }
    System.out.println("Successfully Logged In");
    }


    public static Boolean CheckPassword(String password)
    {
    //perform all password checks
    Boolean passedLength = checkPasswordLength(password);
    Boolean passedLetter = checkPasswordLetter(password);
    return (passedLength && passedLetter);                 

    }

public static String enterPassword(){
    String password;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Password >>");
    password = input.nextLine();    


    return password;
    }


public static Boolean checkPasswordLength(String password){
    //passes if there is a string value, and it has 6+ characters
    return (password != null && password.length >=6);        
    }

public static Boolean checkPasswordLetter(String password){
    System.out.println("More checking here to be added");
    return true; //for now....
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand what you mean about calling one to call another to call another...I will work to get out of this habit.